# How do I use an additional variable on a quadl function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, integral

I am trying to pass a function from another .m file into a quadl call that also takes an extra variable when evaluating the function.

My current call looks like:

```
fun=@fun1
min = 0;
max = 2;
y=quadl(fun, min, max, 0.00001);
```

I want to have fun1 to be evaluated from min to max.

My function in the fun1.m file is:

```
function func=fun1(x)
    func = x^2+x+y
```

How do I pass the 'y' variable in?

I have tried to change the quad call to:

```
y=quadl(fun1(y), min, max, 0.00001);
```

and:

```
y=quadl(fun1(y), min, max, 0.00001);
```

and the function to:

```
function func=fun1(x,y)
    func = x^2+x+y
```

but that does not work.

I have also tried declaring a global variable but it is giving me an undeclared variable error.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `quadl` will be removed in future releases, so it's best to use `integral`.

You should use:

```
function func=fun1(x,y)
    func = x.^2+x+y;         % with .^
```

Then in your other script, you declare `fun` as a function of `x`:

```
y = 5;
fun=@(x)fun1(x,y);
min = 0;
max = 2;
y=integral(fun, min, max);
```

If you insist on using `quadl`, you can do exactly the same:

```
y = 5;
fun=@(x)fun1(x,y);
min = 0;
max = 2;
y=quadl(fun, min, max, 0.00001);
```

---

EDIT:
To keep an expression in function of `y` aft er the integration of `x`, you need to work with `syms` and `int`:

```
syms x y z
fun = fun1(x,y,z);
min = 0;
max = 2;
expr = int(fun,  x, min, max);
```

Comment: How would I define fun1 if I wanted to iterate from 0 to x, and then use y and z?  fun@(x) = fun1(x,y,z) and function fun=fun1(x,y,z) doesn't seem to work with the error: "The integrand function must return an output vector of the same length as the input vector."

Comment: @obizues I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that you want to have an expression for `y` and `z` after the integral?